# perform full text elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I am trying to perform full text elastic search using the below query

```
{
 "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": {
    "match": { "city": "mexico city"}
  }
  
}
}
}
```

I thought the above query would yield the result containing the exact match "Mexico city", however, I am getting the results that contain just Mexico as well. May I know what is wrong with my elastic query please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because match query by default use OR operator to search. So anyone term match then it will return results.

You can change operator as shown below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "city": {
        "query": "mexico city",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `match_phrase` if you want to match exact phrase:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "city": "mexico city"
    }
  }
}
```

Above query will return document only where `mexico city` is matching exactly.

Comment: Yes, it is working with match_phrase, thank you :)

Comment: @balaji Great !! Please accept asnwer as well if it helps you..